# Update a flag/column value with no and set counter to create files in small chunks

Tags: sql, ssis

I have total 60 .txt files that i am trying process and generate 1 output flat file using SSIS package. Those 60 .txt file are loaded in the table.

Now the outputfile will be too big. So I'm trying to divide this file into chunck of 6. So when my ssis package runs, 10 files will process and create 1

output file and again run the ssis package and generate another file. Total will be 6 files.

I have SQL Task  which get those distinct files name in SSIS package and then process. There is one column names `JobDone` which I'm treating as a flag.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FileName FROM Table A WHERE JobDone IS NULL
```

I have declared column name in **Table A as => Bit null**, so SSIS package picks up all files with `JobDone` value is `NULL`

By this above SQL Statement it is going to pick up all those 60 files. Now I want to pick up only 10 files at a time.  I want to update a flag with some no for e.g. 7 with
those 50 files so when my SSIS package runs , it going to take only 10 files.

Once that 10 files process is done in SSIS, want to update flag of `JobDone` to `NUL`L for 10 more files from those 50 files and those 10 files will run, now 40 remaining. Then again I want to update flag as `NULL` for 10 more files and run SSIS pacakge. Till all files being processed and 6 outfile get generate.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like there's a lot going on here. Do you just want to talk about how to do the updating of a bit field or do you want to dig into what might be the bigger problem?

Comment: just want to talk about update

Comment: What else is in `Table A` Does it matter whether File00, File 10, File 30, File 45 and File 59 (assume I listed 10) going into the output file or is there some implicit order (File00-File09) comprise one output batch?

Comment: How big are those files and what is the role of SSIS package besides combining the files?

Comment: don't matter, just total 60 files and want to grab 10 at a time and update flag to something else so it don't pick up those files. So run the 10 files and then SSIS package will update flag with YES to those files where job is done - JobDone  1 and then again from those big chunks of files, i want to update value of Column JobDone = Null so it picks up those files and process them

Comment: SSIS package is just get those files and process them 1 by 1 and generate 1 FLAT FILE output. Since its 60 input files and 1 output file, so i want to grab in small chunks because output file is going to be huge.

Comment: Total could be 5000 KB

Comment: I could do updates manually by getting names of those file but its just so much to keep in mind. I am sure there will be some way in SQL to set the Counter and update value with something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to do what you are asking, my package would look something like this (minus the first step)

Create 2 variables named and object type below

- FileName string
- TableList object

[image: CF]

The Data flow would look like the following. Generally, I hate aggregating in a data flow but here it makes sense. Write you data to the file and also figure out the 10 file names that you used. Write those names to an in memory recordset object (TableList).

[image: Data flow]

Use the Recordset object and shred it (bingle a post by Jamie Thomson for details) and that will help you pull the rows out of the RS object. Inside the ForEach loop you'll execute an UPDATE statement to mark those files as having been processed.

I used the following script to create some data

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM sys.tables AS T 
    WHERE T.name = 'Chunks' AND T.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')
)
BEGIN
    -- Source table
    CREATE TABLE
        dbo.Chunks
    (
        SourceFile varchar(50) NOT NULL
    ,   JobDone bit NULL
    ,   FileData varchar(500) NOT NULL
    );

    -- add some data
    WITH SRC AS
    (
        SELECT
            OBJECT_NAME(AC.object_id) AS SourceFile
        ,   NULL AS bit
        ,   AC.name AS FileData
        FROM
            sys.all_columns AS AC
    )
    , TOP60 AS
    (
        SELECT TOP 60
            SRC.SourceFile
        ,   COUNT(1) AS rc
        FROM
            SRC
        GROUP BY
            SRC.SourceFile
        ORDER BY
            2 DESC
    )
    INSERT INTO
        dbo.Chunks
    (
        SourceFile
    ,   JobDone
    ,   FileData
    )
    SELECT 
        SRC.SourceFile
    ,   SRC.bit
    ,   SRC.FileData
    FROM 
        TOP60 T
        INNER JOIN
            SRC    
            ON SRC.SourceFile = T.SourceFile;
END
```

My OLEDB Source looks like the following query

```
-- grab all the data associated to them
SELECT
    C.SourceFile
,   C.JobDone
,   C.FileData
FROM
    dbo.Chunks AS C
WHERE
    C.SourceFile IN
    (
        -- Grab any 10 sourcefile names that haven't been processed
        SELECT TOP 10
            C.SourceFile
        FROM
            dbo.Chunks AS C
        WHERE
            C.JobDone IS NULL
    )  
ORDER BY
    C.SourceFile;
```

My update statement looks like

```
UPDATE
    C
SET
    JobDone = 1
FROM
    dbo.Chunks AS C
WHERE
    C.JobDone IS NULL
    AND C.FileName = ?;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was very useful. But this point I'm not changing SSIS package. I just want SQL update statement. Something like setting up counter. Initially JobDone will be Null. For Rest of 50 files, I need to change the column JobDone flag to something like 7. So when SSIS package runs, it don't pick up those 50 files. IS there something like setting up a counter with update statement?

Comment: The last statement in my answer is the on that is used to indicate a particular file has been processed. Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: That is already i m doing in my ssis package. Once my file is being processed, I am updating JobDone = 1.

Comment: Could you edit your question to define precisely what you need help with? I know I'm rather confused